# Accessing Swift set elements by their hash value

Tags: swift, hash, set

Say I'm making a chess app, in which a position is stored like this:

```
struct Position {
    var pieces: Set<Piece>
    // some other stuff
}
```

`Piece` is defined as follows:

```
struct Piece: Hashable {
    var row: Int
    var column: Int
    let player: Player
    let type: PieceType

    var hashValue: Int {
        return 8 * row + column
    }
}
```

`Player` and `PieceType` are simple enums:

```
enum Player {
    case White, Black
}

enum PieceType {
    case Queen, King, ...
}
```

Now, I would like to access a `Piece` in a `Position` by its position on the board. The hash value of a `Piece` is uniquely determined by its position, so access to a `Piece` should be possible in constant time. However, a Swift set doesn't have a function to get one of its elements by its hash value. All I could come up with is

```
for piece in pieces {
    if piece.hashValue == 25 {
        // do something
    }
}
```

...but obviously, this runs in linear time, not in constant time.

A way to solve this problem is to not use a set, but an array instead:

```
var pieces: [Piece?]
```

Then I can access the piece at a certain position simply with `pieces[25]`, in constant time. I do find this less elegant, because this method stores the position of each `Piece` twice: by the position in the `pieces` array and by the values of the `row` and `column` variables.

Is there a way to access a set element by its hash value (in constant time)? Or should I just use an array?

Comment: Alternatively use a dictionary [position:piece?], would work as an array but I don't really find this solution "inelegant". Also, using a dictionary, you avoid implicit array index access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preamble:

1. Since there are 64 squares an array of optional pieces is probably best
2. In general you use a dictionary with an Int key as a sparse array (see example below)
3. You should not use hashValue for location alone since it should take into account all properties (I changed to location in example below) - though I get that in this case except transiently no 2 pieces can have the same location and therefore it is probably OK

How I might code it:

```
struct Piece {
    var row: Int
    var column: Int
    let player: Player
    let type: PieceType

    var location: Int {
        return 8 * row + column
    }
}

struct Board {
    var pieces = [Int : Piece]()

    init(pieces: Piece...) {
        pieces.forEach {
            self.pieces[$0.location] = $0
        }
    }
}

let whiteKing = Piece(row: 0, column: 4, player: .White, type: .King)
let blackKing = Piece(row: 7, column: 3, player: .Black, type: .King)

let board = Board(pieces: whiteKing, blackKing)

board.pieces // [4: {row 0, column 4, White, King}, 59: {row 7, column 3, Black, King}]
```

Comment: An array of optionals sounds like a lot of wasted space in case only a few pieces are left. Is that true, or are arrays of optionals optimised well enough?

Comment: There its no optimisation, the space is wasted. However for 64 squares it isn't worth worry about. For a larger array a dictionary as a sparse array is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do:

```
let piece = pieces.filter { $0.hashValue == 25 }[0]
```

You are scanning an 8x8 chessboard. Stop worrying about complexity.

Comment: I wanted to used a set because I don't really care about the order of the elements. However, if an array is easier to implement and the set isn't actually going to improve the running time, then I shouldn't bother. That's why I asked this question :) Besides, a chess board may be small, but in something like a chess engine things like this matter a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Getting an element in a `Set` by it's `hashValue` in constant time generally wouldn't be possible since the properties used to compute the `hashValue` might change (e.g. the `Piece` moves) and the `Set` doesn't know when this has happened. If the `Set` could know somehow then it might be able to store the element in a new location with respect to the `hashValue` to allow subsequent constant lookups. Basically that's what you would be doing if you put them in a `[Position: Piece]` dictionary and added/removed keys for every move.

In this case a simple array is probably the best solution. As for the array wasting space, it's a classic case of a [space–time tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).

Answer (score 1):

To make it more elegant, I would add a *subscript* to a `Board` structure.

```
struct Board {

  var grid: [Piece?]
  let rows: Int, columns: Int

  init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
    self.rows = rows
    self.columns = columns
    grid = [Piece?](count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
  }

  func isValidIndex(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
    return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
  }

  subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Piece? {
    get {
      assert(isValidIndex(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
      return grid[(row * columns) + column]
    }
    set(newValue) {
      assert(isValidIndex(row, column: column), "Index out of range")
      grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

And get/set pieces like this:

```
var board = Board(rows: 8, columns: 8)
board[0, 1] = Piece(player: .White, type: .King)
board[0, 2] // nil
```

Comment: This was already my intention. :) I just don't really want to use an array, because of the waste of space.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with an array.

> I do find this less elegant, because this method stores the position of each Piece twice: by the position in the pieces array and by the values of the row and column variables.

If you could access a value from a set by hash (which you can't) you would have the same problem where the values are stored twice. And an array would be the nicer way to access elements.

```
// array
pieces[25]

// set (not possible)
pieces.elementWithHash(25)
```

I would actually change it to use a 2d array since it is more readable what you are accessing.

```
var pieces: [[Piece?]]
pieces[3][1]
```

Comment: I was planning on making a subscript for the `Position` to access the elements like `myPosition[25]`.

Comment: "If you could access a value from a set by hash (which you can't) you would have the same problem where the values are stored twice." But isn't the point of a hash value that you can quickly access them? I feel like I'm not making use of this property if I simply iterate through all elements.