# Does Swift know not to initialize an object if my set already contains it?

Tags: swift

I have a global `var notes: Set<Note>` that contains notes initialized with downloaded data.

In the code below, does Swift know to skip the initialization of my `Note` object if `notes` already contains it?

```
for dictionary in downloadedNoteDictionaries {
  let note = Note(dictionary: dictionary)
  notes.insert(note)
}
```

I'm wondering because my app downloads dozens of notes per request and initializing a `Note` object seems rather computationally expensive.

If the answer to my question is no, then how could I improve my code's performance?

My `Note` class—which I just realized should probably be a struct instead—has the property `let id: Int64` as its sole essential component, but apparently, you can't [access an element of a set by its hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425578/accessing-swift-set-elements-by-their-hash-value)? I don't want to use `Set`'s instance method `first(where:)` because it has a complexity of O(*n*), and `notes` could contain millions of `Note` objects.

Comment: "seems rather computationally expensive" *seems*, or *is*?

Comment: "seems". I haven't tested it, but I think the `Note` initializer does a lot. It uses a complex decryption algorithm to decrypt its body, and in a similar fashion to how it creates itself, it also creates up to hundreds of `User` objects for its (`sender` & `recipients` properties) and inserts those user objects into a global `var users: Set<User>`, and then it inserts itself and all the users it created into the app's local SQLite database.

Comment: Yeah there's no way the optimizer would cull out something like that. How surprising would it be if the compiler decided to delete a giant chunk of your program? :p "and inserts those user objects into a global var users: Set<User>. " BIG YIKES. "Making users and stuffing them into a global" does not sound anything like "initializing a note". It shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Haha! Well, hey, I never said it was pretty. But the tests are passing. Just kidding. I don't have tests. Anyway, thanks for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on Swift to eliminate the construction of a new `Note` in your code. Your `Set` needs to ask the `Note` for its `hashValue`, and may need to call `==` with your `Note` as an argument. Those computations require the `Note` object. Possibly if Swift can inline everything, it can notice that your `hashValue` and `==` depend only on the `id` property, but it is certainly not guaranteed to notice or to act on that information.

It sounds like you should be using an `[Int64: Note]` instead of a `Set<Note>`.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Use a dictionary instead of a set? Hmm... OK. I guess that'd work better. Thanks. I guess I figured that if Core Data used sets for its objects, then I should too.

Answer (score 0):

No, Swift will not avoid creating the new Note object. The problem here is trying to determine if an object already exists in a set. In order to check if an object already exists in the set, you must have some way to identify this object consistently and have that identification persist across future reads and writes to that set. Assuming we want to adopt Swift's hashing enhancements which deprecates the old methods for having to manually provide a hashValue for any object conforming to the Hashable, we should not use a Set as a solution to this problem. The reason is because Swift's new recommended hashing methods use a random seed to generate hashes for added security. Depending on hash values to identify an element in a set alone would therefore not be possible.

It seems that your method of identifying these objects are by an id. I would do as Rob suggests and use a dictionary where the keys are the id. This would help you answer existential questions in order avoid instantiating a Note object.

If you need the resulting dictionary as a Set, you can still create a new Set from this resulting dictionary sequence.

It is possible to pull out a particular element from a set as long as you know how to identify it, and the operations would be O(1). You would use these two methods:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2996833-firstindex
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2830801-subscript

Here is an example that I was able to run in a playground. However, this assumes that you have a way to identify in your data / model the id of the Note object beforehand in order to avoid creating the Note object. In this case, I am assuming that a Note shares an id with a Dictionary it holds:

```
import UIKit

struct DictionaryThatNoteUses {
    var id: String

    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

struct Note: Hashable {
    let dictionary: DictionaryThatNoteUses

    var id: String {
        return dictionary.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Note, rhs: Note) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

var downloadedNoteDictionaries: [DictionaryThatNoteUses] = [
    DictionaryThatNoteUses(),
    DictionaryThatNoteUses(),
    DictionaryThatNoteUses()
]

var notesDictionary: [String: Note] = [:]
var notesSet: Set<Note> = []

// Add a dictionary with the same id as the first dictionary
downloadedNoteDictionaries.append(downloadedNoteDictionaries.first!) // so now there are four Dictionary objects in this array

func createDictionaryOfNotes() {
    func avoidCreatingDuplicateNotesObject(with id: String) {
        print("avoided creating duplicate notes object with id \(id)") // prints once because of the duplicated note at the end matching the first, so a new Note object is not instantiated
    }

    downloadedNoteDictionaries.forEach {
        guard notesDictionary[$0.id] == nil else { return avoidCreatingDuplicateNotesObject(with: $0.id) }

        let note = Note(dictionary: $0)
        notesDictionary[note.id] = note
    }
}

createDictionaryOfNotes()

// Obtain a set for set operations on those unique Note objects
notesSet = Set<Note>(notesDictionary.values)

print("number of items in dictionary = \(notesDictionary.count), number of items in set = \(notesSet.count)") // prints 3 and 3 because the 4th object was a duplicate

// Grabbing a specific element from the set
// Let's test with the second Note object from the notesDictionary
let secondNotesObjectFromDictionary = notesDictionary.values[notesDictionary.values.index(notesDictionary.values.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]
let thirdNotesObjectFromDictionary = notesDictionary.values[notesDictionary.values.index(notesDictionary.values.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)]

if let secondNotesObjectIndexInSet = notesSet.firstIndex(of: secondNotesObjectFromDictionary) {
    print("do the two objects match: \(notesSet[secondNotesObjectIndexInSet] == secondNotesObjectFromDictionary)") // prints true
    print("does the third object from dictionary match the second object from the set: \(thirdNotesObjectFromDictionary == notesSet[secondNotesObjectIndexInSet])") // prints false
}
```